# WordPress get_post_type, how to display name of label

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, custom-post-type

Hi stackflow community,

I'm fairly new to PHP, so please excuse any mistakes.
For Wordpress I have registered a custom post type called ('energy') (see code).
I know that with the command `<PHP echo get_post_type();><?/>.` I can call the name of the post type and I get `energy` as a result. But I want to call the `'name'` that is situated in the `'labels'` array. The `Energy & Transport` - how do I do that?
I read it's possible with `get_post_type_object();` but, a) I don't know if that's true and b) I don't know how to construct the correct command.

Can anyone please help me to get the correct command? Thanks in advance.

```
CUSTOM POST TYPE:

register_post_type('energy', array(
  'public' => true,
  'show_in_rest' => true,
  'has_archive' => true,
  'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
  'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-lightbulb',
  'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => 'Energy & Transport',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Post for Energy & Transport',
    'all_items'=> 'All Energy & Transport Posts',
  )
  ));
```

Comment: <PHP echo get_post_type();><?/> should be <?php echo get_post_type(); ?>

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `get_post_type()` and `get_post_type_object()`

```
<?php
    // Get the post type  
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    // Get the post type object based on the post type;
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );

    // Gets the name properties of the post type object.
    $post_type_name = $post_type_object->labels->name;
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_object/

Answer (score 0):

So you just need to learn a bit more about objects and arrays really.

You are using the right function `get_post_type_object();`

In order to access the labels you need to descend the object like so

```
$energy = get_post_type_object( 'energy' );
echo $energy->labels->name;
```

Here is the documentation on objects:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! I was on the right path then!
I actually used it like this now: 

```$custompost = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() );
echo $custompost->labels->name;```

Because I have more custom post types, not just energy. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You can try with the below code -

```
<?php 
    $custom_post_type = get_post_type();
    $custom_post_type_data = get_post_type_object( $post_type );

    $custom_post_type_name = $custom_post_type_data->labels->name;
```